# Are asynchronous callbacks required?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

If one has the following method with a callback:

```
public async Task MethodWithCallback(Action callback)
{
  await _myService.SomeExcitingAsync(); 
  callback();
}
```

Is it safe/recommended to pass in an asynchronous callback, as in:

```
await MethodWithCallback(async () =>
  {
    await _myOtherService.AnotherExcitingAsync();
  });
```

Or is it advised that I provide an async version of my method as below? Does it make any difference?

```
public async Task MethodWithCallback(Func<Task> callback) {
  await _myService.SomeExcitingAsync(); 
  await callback();
}
```

Comment: `If one has the following method with a callback` But why? Tasks replace completion callbacks. The method returns a `Task`, thus it does not need a callback at all.

Comment: My example code was deliberately contrived to supplement the question. The real method which made me ask this question is more complex and does legitimately take a Func - all of which makes me realise that one needs to be doubly careful with async code when passing in lambdas as it's very easy to use an async lambdas when one isn't expected.

Comment: (Also, my choice of word 'callback' was poor - I meant a Func/Action rather than a completion callback.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

If the callback code is asynchronous, have the delegate return a `Task`.

**the long**

While you can assign an async lambda to an `Action`, it probably doesn't have the behavior you're expecting. It creates what is equivalent to an `async void` method.

The result is that while the lambda is async, the caller of the delegate would not be able to wait for it to finish and would not be able to see its result. Any uncaught exceptions would be lost.

While this is allowed by C# and there are extremely rare circumstances where code might be very carefully made with these caveats in mind, the general rule of thumb is to never do this.